# Symfony2: Create role mapping in config for custom user provider

Tags: symfony

I have a very basic custom user provider that loads users from my database (it's very similar to the built in entity provider). Instead of storying roles in the database as well, *I want to manually hard code role assignments into a config file* (the security.yml file makes the most sense).

My `User` entity implements `UserInterface` so it has a `getRoles()` method, but I can't put log in there to read the role mapping from the configuration because it's the model layer.

I don't really know where to get started with this. It seems like I need some other area to lookup the role mapping and assign the role to the user. Should I a Doctrine postLoad listener service for my `User` entity and then load the config there and assign the role?